# Two definitions of set of class $C^1$, given in books by Brezis and Evans

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, smooth-manifolds

I am reading the book *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations, by Haim Brezis*. It is given the following definition of an open set of class $C^1$, which I find it hard to understand intuitivelly:

> We define the following sets:
>
> - $R_+ = \{x=(x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n \ | \ x_n \geq 0\} $
>
>   - $ Q = \{x=(x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n \ | \ (\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i^2)^{1/2} < 1 \ y \  |x_n|<1 \}$
>   - $ Q_+=R_+ \cap Q $
>   - $ Q_0=\{(x_1,...,x_{n-1},0) \in \mathbb{R}^n \ | \ (\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i^2)^{1/2} < 1 \}$
>
> An open set $\Omega$ is of class $C^1$ if for every $x \in \partial \Omega$ there exists a neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and
>   a bijective map $H: Q \to U_x$ such that:
>
> - $H \in C^1(\overline{Q})$
> - $H^{-1} \in C^1(\overline{U_x})$
> - $H(Q_+)=U_x \cap Q$
> - $H(Q_0)= U_x \cap \partial \Omega$

Is this the same definition than the one given in Evans' book for k=1 restricted to bounded sets?

[image]

I suppose this has to do with the fact that the boundary of $\Omega$ is some kind of $C^1$ function...

Answer (score 2):

The definitions are equivalent. Brezis says: locally, the domain can be mapped onto half-space by a $C^1$-diffeomorphism. Evans says: locally, the domain is bounded by the graph of a $C^1$-function.

Evans$\implies$Brezis: the domain $x_n>\gamma(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})$ is mapped onto upper halfspace by $$H(x_1,\dots,x_n) = x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}, x_n - \gamma(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})$$ 
This is indeed a diffeomorphism, because 
$$H^{-1}(x_1,\dots,x_n) = x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}, x_n + \gamma(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})$$

Brezis$\implies$Evans: by the implicit function theorem, the set where then $n$th component of $H$ is $0$ is a smooth hypersurface. Make a tangent plane to it a coordinate hyperplane; you get (again from IFT) a smooth function $\gamma$ for which this surface is a graph.

Comment: Could you expand the argument $Brezis \Rightarrow Evans$ a little bit more? Thanks in advance.